# Immediately resolved Observable - equivalent of $q.when()

Tags: asynchronous, angular, observable

While doing my first Angular 2 CRUD exercise, I am trying to re-use my edit form to both add new and edit an existing object.

I am having this improper code:

```
this._route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
      let id = params['id'];
      if (id) {
        this._productService.getProduct(id)
          .subscribe(
            product => this.product = product,
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
          );
      } else {
        this.product = {
          name: 'default name',
          ean: '',
          price: 0,
          qty: 0,
          imageUrl: '',
          _id: ''
        };
      }

    });

    (<FormGroup>this.registerForm).setValue(this.product, {onlySelf: true});
```

... which no wonder does not work - because one part of the `if` is sync, the other - async.

I want to optimize the code and convert the static default object template into a value from an immediately resolved Observable - basically an equivalent of `$q.when(myVar)`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now I know it'd be:

```
      return Observable.of({
          name: 'default name',
          ean: '',
          price: 0,
          qty: 0,
          imageUrl: '',
          _id: ''
      });
```